# Group By asking for extra columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We are trying to run this query.

```
select ccr.id as id, ccr.title as name, c.name as contract, ccr.status as status
from change_request   ccr 
LEFT JOIN contract c ON ccr.contract_id = c.id 
where ccr.id < 2000
GROUP BY ccr.id, c.id
order by id
```

it is throwing error
********* Error *********

ERROR: column "ccr.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 22

Why it is asking for multiple column from same table. I mean if we do group by ccr.id, then all columns from same table should not be asked.

More interestingly is that following query (similar to above) runs fine.

```
select aim.id as id, aim.name as name, c.name as contract, aim.planned_completion_date as plannedcompetitiondate

from action_item_mgmt aim 
LEFT JOIN contract c ON aim.contract_id = c.id 

WHERE aim.id < 2000
group by aim.id, c.id
order by id
```

Comment: Is `ccr.id` a primary key of the change_request table? I know logically it sounds like it is but identity columns are not necessarily primary keys. In order for Postgresql to know that other columns in the table are functionally dependent on `id` it has to be marked as a primary key

Comment: Thanks, we got the problem. it is exactly this only. It's not a primary key.

Comment: Your query will work if you are using MySQL. But for other database server it is mandatory to specify every columns except that columns which contains aggregate functions.

Comment: @GarethD, Please post your comment as an answer. I will mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @SaharshShah That is not true, the SQL Standard allows columns/expressions in the select that are not contained in the group by or an aggregate as long as they are functionally dependent on a column in the group by. Postresql has partially implemented this. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4a6a4/1), or for more reading I have recently done a relatively in depth [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20357066/1048425) discussing MySQLs (very loose) implementation of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see that your first query would not work is if the column `id` is not the primary key of the change_request table.

If you make it the primary key your first query should work fine, although as has been said, the grouping does seem fairly redundant with no aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no aggregation (like `count()`, `sum()`, `avg()`, etc) in either query: Remove the `group by` clause altogether.

Comment: In actual query there are more tables (I cannot post the exact query). While debugging for this error I reduced the query to this simple query. Also why the other query is running fine.

Comment: but there are no aggregate functions used, so `group by` is meaningless